# How to handle the $filter query GET operation and show Status Code 204 for get request for which data doesn't exist

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, odata, restful-url

I am sending the below GET URI with filter query which is returning emapty value like "Value":[].

`https://localhost:44372/api/V1/Customers?$filter=CustomerName eq 'NTPC'`

but my requirement is that to show the response body empty means nothing should come in response body and the status code should show `204 No Content`.

where do i need to handle the get request to show the 204(No Content) status code.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a CustomersController, and the method you're calling returns `HttpResponseMessage`, you can simply use `Request.CreateResponse` like so:

```cs
return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, user);
```

or

```cs
return request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)204, user);
```

Comment: I am using OData controller where it will just prepare the query part. it will be not evaluated. so i am not able to get the value whether it is 0 value or more than 0.

GET operation code

`public IQueryable<Customers > GetCustomers()
        {
            return db.Customers ;
        }`

here db.Customers will be having the select query only not the execution result in OData.